# Missing slices of piechat in iPhone6 works fine for iphone5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, pie-chart, iphone-6

I am using BNPieChart. Slices of Piechart in iPhone6s (iOS 10.2.1) gone missing but same code works fine for iPhone5s (iOS 10.2.1) and iPhone5s (iOS 10.2.1).

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    CGRect pieFrame = CGRectMake(30, 78, 240, 240);
    self.chart = [[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:pieFrame];

    BNColor *emergencyColor = [BNColor colorWithRed:142.0/255.0 green:1.0/255.0 blue:32.0/255.0];
    BNColor *urgentColor = [BNColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0 green:133.0/255.0 blue:8.0/255.0];
    BNColor *nonUrgentColor = [BNColor colorWithRed:97.0/255.0 green:147.0/255.0 blue:3.0/255.0];

    self.chart.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:emergencyColor,urgentColor,nonUrgentColor, nil];

    [self.chart addSlicePortion:emergencyCount/totalCount withName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%",(emergencyCount/totalCount)*100]];
    [self.chart addSlicePortion:urgentCount/totalCount withName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%",(urgentCount/totalCount)*100]];
    [self.chart addSlicePortion:nonUrgentCount/totalCount withName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%",(nonUrgentCount/totalCount)*100]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.chart];
}
```

On iphone6 its only display gradient dark gray circle, Have look in image:
[image]

But it works fine for iPhone5(iOS 10.2.1)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it needs to be changed in `BNPieChart` classes itself. There was incompatibility between `CGFloat` and `float*`
Replace the following lines of code in `BNPieChart.m` wherever they are written:

```
//  CGFloat red, green, blue;
//  [self getRGBForIndex:index red:&red green:&green blue:&blue];
```

To

```
CGFloat red, green, blue;
BNColor *color = [colors objectAtIndex:(index % [colors count])];
red = color.red;
green = color.green;
blue = color.blue;
```

Watch `viewDidAppear` to achieve the result. It works fine if anybody has implemented `BNPieChart`like I did.